# Build object from another object or array in Google Apps Script and javascript/jQuery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I am receiving the following object with the function in my Spreadsheet Add-on with Google Apps Script:

**Function:**

```
function collectAllData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(DATA);
  var fileData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(fileData);
  return fileData;
}
```

**Object Received:**

```
[[File ID 1, File Name 1, File Type 1, File Category 1, File Image 1, File Description 1], [File ID 2, File Name 2, File Type 2, File Category 2, File Image 2, File Description 2], ...]
```

I need to convert this object to the following object in my HTML template

```
 <script>
    try {
            var file_data = ({
                'File ID 1':{
                    id:"File ID 1",
                    name:"File Name 1",
                    type:"File Type 1"
                    cat:"File Category 1",
                    desc:"File Description 1",
                    img:"File Image 1"
                },
                'File ID 2':{
                    id:"File ID 2",
                    name:"File Name 2",
                    type:"File Type 2"
                    cat:"File Category 2",
                    desc:"File Description 2",
                    img:"File Image 2"
                }
            });
        } catch(e) {
            var file_data = null;
        }
    </script>
```

Is there any proper way of doing this in my `Code.gs` and then passing it to the `template.html`?

I am currently building this in my `template.html`, but I am sure that there are better ways to do this. Additionally, I constantly get the following error: `SyntaxError: missing } after property list`

here is my current code from my `template.html`

```
  <script>
  try {
  var file_data = ({
  <? for (var i=1; i<fileData.length; i++){
  var x = i < fileData.length-1 ? ',' : ''; ?>
    '<?!= fileData[i][8] ?>':{
       id:"<?!= fileData[i][8] ?>",
       title:"<?!= fileData[i][0] ?>",
       ext:"<?!= fileData[i][1] ?>",
       cat:"<?!= fileData[i][2] ?>",
       cost:"<?!= fileData[i][3] ?>",
       desc:'<?!= fileData[i][4] ?>',
       img:"<?!= fileData[i][5] ?>",
       url:"<?!= fileData[i][6] ?>",
       status:"<?!= fileData[i][7] ?>"
  }<?!= x;
  }?>
  });
  } catch(err) {
    var file_data = null;
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: How did you call collectAllData() and where is it returning?

Comment: `function browseT(){
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Files");
  htmlOutput.fileData = collectAllData();
  var htmlParams = htmlOutput.evaluate().setWidth(700).setHeight(540);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlParams, 'File Browser');
}`

Comment: There is no htmlOutput property or method named fileData.  And anyway htmlService is a server side process.  I suggest that you read [Client Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, will read it. I was under the impression that fileData method was here: `htmlOutput.fileData = collectAllData();`

Comment: The first time I read  and understood Client to Server Communication it opened up a whole new world for me.  I use google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().functionName() to call server functions and return data to the clientside all of the time.

Comment: By the way, if you're going to use html templates with scriptlets then when you call the HtmlService... on the template file you will have to use the evaluate method.  You can call server side functions in the template because that process occurs server side before the DOM loads.

Comment: I suppose I could go this way and call `google.script.run.collectAllData();` from the HTML template, but the problem remains, I still have to convert the initial data array to an object, which I cannot do for some reason.

Comment: The problem with that is that without the withSuccessHandler then you have no way to receive the data from the server.  This handler essentially creates a listener for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily stringify the data and send it to client[<sup>1</sup>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) and parse it client side.

#### Snippet:

Server side:

```
function collectAllData(){
.
.
  return JSON.stringify(fileData); 
}
```

ClientSide:

```
<script>
var file_data={};
google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(parseArray)
    .collectAllData();

function parseArray(arr){
arr = JSON.parse(arr);
arr.forEach((row)=>{
  file_data[row[0]] ={
    id:row[0],
    name:row[1],
    type:row[2],
    cat:row[3],
    desc:row[5],
    img:row[4]
  }
})
console.log(file_data);
}
</script>
```

You can also do the parsing server side and pass the stringified parsed object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How would I do the parsing server-side and receive the desired object?

Comment: @AlexB Same way I did on the client side. Only difference is arrow syntax`=>` isn't supported.

Comment: what would be the substitute of `=>` in the `.gs`?

Comment: Search, [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), mediate on what you read and **practice**!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
  window.onload=function(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHander(fileData){
      for(var i=0;i<fileData.length;i++) {
      {
        var file_dataA.push({id:fileData[i][8],title:fileData[i][0],ext:fileData[i][1],cat:fileData[i][2],cost:fileData[i][3],desc:fileData[i][4],img:fileData[i][5],url:fileData[i][6],status:fileData[i][7]});
      }
    }
   .collectAllData();
  </script>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

You also use the JQuery ready function as well.

gs:

```
function collectAllData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(DATA);
  var fileData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return fileData;
}
```

Very often I build the html on the server side and pass it as a string to the client and then just load into a div with `$("#id").html()` or `getElementById().innerHTML=`

Comment: Not that it matters much, but OP wants a object file_data: `{id1:{},id2:{},id3:{}...}`. I think yours will create a array `[]`.

Comment: @TheMaster Yeh.  I hesitated even answering because I didn't want to seem like I was competing for a few points.  But I thought it might be helpful to OP.

Comment: I want to thank you both for your contribution and help, but at this point, I would stick with the answer given by @TheMaster

Comment: @AlexB Good choice. Please be sure to check TheMaster answer.

Comment: @Cooper, I have and I was able to create the object, but still having trouble to insert it to my HTML. All I need in my HTML is the desired file_data variable with the object in it so that I can access all items from the rest of my code to manipulate the data the way I need

Comment: @AlexB Actually, you haven't.  A big green check mark will appear next to the answer when you have.  In your question, you describe an object of objects where the key to each sub object is the file Id.   I assumed that you probably didn't want that.  I assumed that you really wanted and array of objects that would be deconstructed like this: `var html='';for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) { html+=Utilities.formatString('FileId:' %s......',vA[i].id....);` I believe to use want you actually asked for you would have to know what the fileId is first which I suspect that you don't have. I could be wrong.

Comment: @AlexB Note: What TheMaster says in the first comment in this section.

Comment: @Cooper, I do have a fields from my spreadsheet that I use as a database for all all of the available files including any data that needs to be provided. The fiels are constant, unless I add some additional files to this DB.

Comment: So what I am trying to do is to get the data from the spreadsheet (DB) and have it available in between the script tags in my HTML

Comment: What script tags? Show me an example.

Comment: '<script>try {
  var file_data = ({
  <? for (var i=1; i<fileData.length; i++){
  var x = i < fileData.length-1 ? ',' : ''; ?>
    '<?!= fileData[i][8] ?>':{
       id:"<?!= fileData[i][8] ?>",
       title:"<?!= fileData[i][0] ?>",
       ext:"<?!= fileData[i][1] ?>",
       cat:"<?!= fileData[i][2] ?>",
       cost:"<?!= fileData[i][3] ?>",
       desc:'<?!= fileData[i][4] ?>',
       img:"<?!= fileData[i][5] ?>",
       url:"<?!= fileData[i][6] ?>",
       status:"<?!= fileData[i][7] ?>"
  }<?!= x;
  }?>
  });
  } catch(err) {
    var file_data = null;
  }
  </script>`

Comment: You might be able to do that with the Google Apps Script Rest API.  i don't really know because I've never used it.  You can't do it after the html has already loaded because those printing scriptlets are evaluated server side before document loads.

Comment: @Cooper, I thought that this would be the case. I will try it, thanks for your support

Comment: @AlexB See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices Use jQuery to append tags after receiving  `file_data` from server.